# reading an integer from the command line using rust

Tags: rust

I have the following code to create a string of length n+1, where n is passed as a command line argument:

```
let args: Vec<String> = env::args().collect();
let min_no_of_bytes =  &args[2].parse::<u64>();
let no_of_times_to_repeat =  min_no_of_bytes as usize;
let mut inputtext='0'.to_string().repeat(no_of_times_to_repeat);
```

But I get the following error during compile:

```
error[E0606]: casting `&Result<u64, ParseIntError>` as `usize` is invalid
  --> src/main.rs:33:17
   |
33 |     let temp =  min_no_of_bytes as usize;
   |                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
   = help: cast through a raw pointer first
```

Please advise. Thanks.

Comment: `parse::<u64>()` returns a Result because parsing could fail. You need to handle that result.

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems that are unhandled in the original code.

- `args` is not guaranteed to have a second argument, therefore `&args[2]` could panic
- the string at `&args[2]` is not guaranteed to be a parseable number and therefore `parse` returns a `Result`, which may carry an error.

Direct array access is discouraged in general, in Rust. It is of course possible, but it can panic and is slow. So if you want to access an array, you would usually use *iterators* or the `.get()` function.

---

### *Handling all the errors*

First, I'd recommend handling all the errors before we make it a bit more pretty. The rust compiler should force you to do that if you avoid direct array accesses and `unwrap`:

```rust
use std::env;

fn main() {
    let args: Vec<String> = env::args().collect();

    let arg = match args.get(2) {
        Some(val) => val,
        None => {
            println!("Not enough arguments provided!");
            return;
        }
    };

    let min_no_of_bytes = match arg.parse::<u64>() {
        Ok(val) => val,
        Err(e) => {
            println!("Unable to parse number from argument: {}", e);
            return;
        }
    };

    let no_of_times_to_repeat = min_no_of_bytes as usize;
    let inputtext = '0'.to_string().repeat(no_of_times_to_repeat);

    println!("{}", inputtext);
}
```

Running this program with: `cargo run -- bla 3` prints `000`.

---

### *Setting up proper error handling*

If you realize we now have `println!(...error)` and `return` right next to each other. Instead, we could directly return an error from main to combine those two actions. Rust will then automatically print the error.

In order to accept any error type, this can be done with the type `Result<(), Box<dyn Error>>` or wrapping types like [anyhow](https://docs.rs/anyhow/latest/anyhow/).

I'll provide the `anyhow` solution here, because I think it's in general better to use a wrapper library instead of `Box<dyn Error>` directly.

```rust
use anyhow::{anyhow, Result};
use std::env;

fn main() -> Result<()> {
    let args: Vec<String> = env::args().collect();

    let arg = args
        .get(2)
        .ok_or(anyhow!("Not enough arguments provided!"))?;

    let min_no_of_bytes = arg.parse::<u64>()?;

    let no_of_times_to_repeat = min_no_of_bytes as usize;
    let inputtext = '0'.to_string().repeat(no_of_times_to_repeat);

    println!("{}", inputtext);

    Ok(())
}
```

Note the `?` operator here, which is a quick way of saying "if this is an `Err` value, return it from the function, otherwise unwrap the value". Basically the safe, error-propagating version of `.unwrap()`.

---

### *Using a proper command line parsing library*

I won't go into further detail here, but if your projects get a little bigger than 10 lines of code, you will quickly discover that writing argument parsing manually is pretty tedious.

There are several libraries that make this process very easy. The one I'd recommend at the time of writing this is [clap](https://docs.rs/clap/latest/clap/):

```rust
use clap::Parser;

/// A program that does things
#[derive(Parser, Debug)]
#[clap(version, about)]
struct Args {
    /// Minimum number of bytes
    #[clap(short)]
    min_no_of_bytes: u64,
}

fn main() {
    let args = Args::parse();

    let no_of_times_to_repeat = args.min_no_of_bytes as usize;
    let inputtext = '0'.to_string().repeat(no_of_times_to_repeat);

    println!("{}", inputtext);
}
```

This requires `clap = { version = "3.1", features = ["derive"] }` in your `Cargo.toml`.

Running it with `cargo run -- -m 3` gives you `000`.

The cool side effect is that you get a help message for free:

`cargo run -- -h`

```
my-program 0.1.0
A program that does things

USAGE:
    my-program.exe -m <MIN_NO_OF_BYTES>

OPTIONS:
    -h, --help                  Print help information
    -m <MIN_NO_OF_BYTES>        Minimum number of bytes
    -V, --version               Print version information
```

Answer (score -2):

The following worked:

```
let args: Vec<String> = env::args().collect();
let min_no_of_bytes = *(&args[2].parse::<usize>().unwrap());
let mut inputtext='0'.to_string().repeat(no_of_times_to_repeat);
```

Comment: While it works, you're not really handling the possible error, you are ignoring it instead. Failure to parse the integer string will cause the code to panic. I'm afraid I have to downvote this answer until it is modified to provide a more idiomatic solution, because it promotes bad error handling practices.

Comment: Also, I find it a bit strange to change the original `parse` of a `u64` into a parse of a `i32`. IMO it should parse a `usize` directly, or a `u32` so you are always sure the cast will not fail and you really don't want a `usize`. Anything else will just delay a panic (that is, if it could not have been parsed as a `usize`, then it's going to fail anyways, so better catch the error when you have a `Result`).